# During synchronization Foreign key null (error)

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, data-synchronization

In my database I want to synchronize two tables. I use auth_user(Default table provided by Django) table for registration and there was another table user-profile that contain entities username, email, age etc. During the synchronization how to update Foriegn key?

```
def get_filename(instance,filename):
    return "upload_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'),filename)

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["created"]:
        p = profile(username = kwargs["instance"], email=kwargs["instance"])
        p.save()

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)

class profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    email  = models.EmailField()
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='15')
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to='get_filename')
    auth_user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Here in table profile during synchronization all columns are filled except auth_user_id. and  there was an error

```
 Exception Value:   

(1048, "Column 'auth_user_id_id' cannot be null")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to alter your table and change the column auth_user_id_id datatype attribute that allows null.

Something like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY auth_user_id_id int;
```

Assuming auth_user_id_id  as int datatype.(Columns are nullable by default)